# Java unmarshal string xml to generic type class

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs, marshalling, unmarshalling

I wanna **convert string xml to Object type class**. Because I have a rest service which returns Object type. Because I need to return response as a dynamically created xml based on response string. But when I am trying to convert string xml to Object class it shows following error :

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element

I will share my codes for you , maybe I did any mistake.

**Service method:**

```
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public  Object sendReqXML(RequestModel request)
{
    try {

        XmlAPI.getInstance().addHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        XmlAPI.getInstance().addHeader("SOAPAction",request.getAction());
        return XmlAPI.getInstance().post(request.getUrl(), request.getAction(), Parser.loadXML(request.getData()), new CallBackEpul());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

**Parser method:**

```
 public static Object loadXMLToObject(String xml) throws Exception
{
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Object.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
   //jaxbUnmarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

    StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
    Object object = (Object) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

    //LOGGER.info(car.toString());
    return object;
}
```

**xml string :**

```
"<ResultCodes>UnknownError</ResultCodes><Description>Unknown Error</Description>"
```

I have a doubt that maybe it related with **@xmlrootelement** must be declared inside the return type object. Because when I created model class which has **@XmlRootElement** and **@XmlElement** tags and return itself it works ok for object class.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's enough to set **@Produces** as **APPLICATION_XML** and return String:

```
@POST
 @Path("/post")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces (MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
 public String sendReqXML(RequestModel request)
{
    try {

        /** JSON API **/
        //JsonAPI.getInstance().addHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        //JsonAPI.getInstance().addHeader("SOAPAction",request.getAction());
        //JsonAPI.getInstance().post(request.getUrl(), request.getAction(), Parser.loadXML(request.getData()), new CallBackEpul());

        /** XML API **/
        XmlAPI.getInstance().addHeader("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        XmlAPI.getInstance().addHeader("SOAPAction",request.getAction());
        return XmlAPI.getInstance().post(request.getUrl(), request.getAction(), Parser.loadXML(request.getData()), new CallBackEpul());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }

}
```